# How to call this delpoyed contract?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

I need some help I want transfer the eth balance in smart contract. The eth is stack there since the distribution is finish and there is no token left, but still somebody continue to send eth to smart contract. We want to refund eth but we need to recover first the fund .Please help us! We are not so familiar in calling of functions in smart contract this is the code below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
library SafeMath {
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    if (a == 0) {  return 0;}
    uint256 c = a * b; assert(c / a == b); return c;
  }
  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a / b;return c;
  }
  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);return a - b;
  }
  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;assert(c >= a);return c;
  }
}
contract ERC20Basic {
  uint256 public totalSupply;
  function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}
contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}
contract BasicToken is ERC20 {
  using SafeMath for uint256;
  mapping(address => uint256) balances;
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }
  function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }
}
contract ERC20Standard is BasicToken {
  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) internal allowed;
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[_from]);
    require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);
    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }
  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }
  function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint _addedValue) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = allowed[msg.sender][_spender].add(_addedValue);
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }
  function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint _subtractedValue) public returns (bool) {
    uint oldValue = allowed[msg.sender][_spender];
    if (_subtractedValue > oldValue) {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
    } else {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = oldValue.sub(_subtractedValue);
    }
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }
}
contract FUNTOKEN is ERC20Standard {
    string public constant name = "FUNTOKEN";
    string public constant symbol = "FUN";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
    uint256 public constant maxSupply = 100000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));
    uint256 public FUNToEth;
    uint256 public ethInWei;    
    address public devWallet;
    function FUNTOKEN () public {
        totalSupply = maxSupply;
        balances[msg.sender] = maxSupply;
        FUNToEth = 10000000;
        devWallet = msg.sender;
      }
    function() payable{
        ethInWei = ethInWei + msg.value;
        uint256 amount = msg.value * FUNToEth;
        if (balances[devWallet] < amount) {return;}//require
        balances[devWallet] = balances[devWallet] - amount;
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] + amount;
        Transfer(devWallet, msg.sender, amount);
        devWallet.send(msg.value);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be only one place where ether is sent from this contract:

```
devWallet.send(msg.value);
```

It's the last line of the anonymous fallback function.

Unfortunately, that function does an early return if someone tries to buy more tokens than are available, so any ether sent when there are no tokens left is permanently locked up in this contract.

Comment: If I create another contract to refund those who mistakenly send the eth Can you teach how to call the function to distribute all the holders? Please sir

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. The ether locked in this contract is locked forever.